# How can I derive the following Linear Programming

Tags: linear-programming

How can we derive the dual problem?

max$_{x}  v^{T} x$

subject to $w^{T} x \le W, 0 \le x_i \le 1 ( i=1,...,n )$

where $ v \in \Bbb {R}^{n}, w_i \in \Bbb {R}^{n} $ and $ W \in \Bbb {R} $

Comment: What is $w$? if $v \in R$, then how can you write $v^Tx$ assuming $x \in R^n$ ? Plz correct your Q.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Assuming $v \in R^n$, you can rewrite your problem as:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{x}{\text{-minimize}}
& & -v^Tx \\
& \text{subject to}
& & w^Tx \leq W, x \leq 0, -x \leq 1 \; .
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Forming [Lagrangian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier), we get:
\begin{equation}
L(x,\lambda,\mu_1,\mu_2)=v^Tx +\lambda(w^Tx-W)+\mu_1x+\mu_2(-x-1)
\end{equation}
Now, you can find dual by solving the following:
\begin{equation}
D(\lambda,\mu_1,\mu_2)=\min_x L(x,\lambda,\mu_1,\mu_2)
\end{equation}